# What is the URI of TOMCAT 10 JSTL for JSP, changing "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" to the new URI?

Tags: tomcat, uri, jstl

I using tomcat 10 and it's standard libraries, in this case the jsp-api.jar with contains the Taglib.
Since tomcat 10 all the components are renamed from javax to jakarta and the jstl is changed from http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core to a new URI that i searching for.

I receive the error on eclipse "can not find the tag library descriptor [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"](http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core%22)

When i run the application after successfully compile i receive at runtime the error exception:

"Die absolute URI: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core%5C] kann weder durch web.xml noch durch die JAR-Files dieser Anwendung aufgelöst werden"

I expect to find the URI for the tomcat 10 standard JSTL library

I try:

```
\<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %\>
```

I expect:

<%@ taglib uri="the new uri hier..." prefix="c" %>

Comment: The  URI has not changed. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core%5C` is indeed not the same as `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`. And further the `jsp-api.jar` does absolutely not contain JSTL.

Comment: You should follow the directions given at info page. Remove the other jars.

Comment: After deploying the JSTL Version 2.0 as explaned in the info all is working. close this issue and thanks a lot.